# Prevent PHP preg_replace to replace text inside shortcode tag

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, shortcode

In WordPress we can use shortcode function inside a post content using this format:

> [shortcode]data[/shortcode]

for example:

> [shortcode]Lorem ipsum[/shortcode]
>   dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit. Praesent laoreet fermentum
>   lacinia. Ut molestie purus interdum
>   lacus pharetra placerat.

My question is, what is the regular expression that we need to replace any text inside the post content Except the one inside the shortcode?

Answer (score 2):

Question doesn't say what text to be replaced and by what. Consider this code to do search/replacement of some pattern outside `shortcode` tag.

**Objective:** To italicize each occurrence of `foo` but not inside `shortcode` tag.

```
$str = "foo
 bar[shortcode]foo[/shortcode]foo 123
 bar [shortcode]foo[/shortcode] foo"; // post content
$query = "foo"; // search pattern

$query = preg_quote($query, '~');
$p = '~((\[shortcode\])(?(2).*?\[/shortcode\])(?:.*?))*?(' . $query . ')~smi';
$s = preg_replace($p, "$1<i>$3</i>", $str);
var_dump($s);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
String(100) "<i>foo</i>
 bar[shortcode]foo[/shortcode]<i>foo</i> 123
 bar [shortcode]foo[/shortcode] <i>foo</i>"
```

As you can see above output encloses search text `foo` to italicized text *ONLY* outside the `shortcode` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/.*\[shortcode]([^[]*)\[\/shortcode].*/\1/gm
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The OP wants to replace text that *isn't* inside the tag.

Comment: @tim look again, see the back reference

Comment: I see the back reference. How do you plan on using this to replace text outside the tag?

Comment: .*\[shortcode] matches everything before (and including) the tag, [\/shortcode].* matches everything after the tag.  everything inside is ( captured ) inside the back reference...  the replacement string is only the back reference...  in short, the entire string is replaced by what is back referenced  inside the tags.  am i wrong?

Comment: You're right about that. I might be wrong, but I think what he's trying to do is make specific replacements on the outer section, not strip it away entirely.

Comment: This is what OP wrote: `My question is, what is the regular expression that we need to replace any text inside the post content Except the one inside the shortcode?` That means he/she wants to replace some text in the post content **if that text is NOT enclosed in shortcode tags**

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match everything that is in-between *shortcode* tags, and nothing else:

- `(?<=\[shortcode]).*?(?=\[/shortcode])`

It looks for positions right after `[shortcode]`, then matches any string -- as short as possible -- that ends right before `[/shortcode]`.

If you want to print all these inbetween-strings in PHP, you need code like this:

```
preg_match_all('%(?<=\[shortcode\]).*?(?=\[/shortcode\])%s',
                               $input, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    echo $result[0][$i];
}
```

If you want to use the caught text outside the loop, then replace the `echo $result[0][$i];` line with:

- `$output .= $result[0][$i];`

Comment: How can OP use this to alter text outside the tag?

Comment: @Tim Yates Replace echo line with concatenation to a variable. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: OP wants to use a regex to alter the text outside the tag, but not inside. Your solution does capture the text inside without altering it, but it *doesn't* allow you to alter the text outside--it just strips it away. Concatenating it to a variable doesn't help, unless that variable has the (modified) text from outside, which brings us back to square one.